# Copy multiple times before pasting all of the contents in vim

Tags: vim, copy-paste, yank

In vim, would there be a way to copy multiple times, accumulate each of them into the clipboard, and then later paste all of them at once where each contents are separated by newline?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [uppercase registers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_alpha) to append. For example, let's clear and yank a line to register `"a`, append a line, append another line, then paste:

```
"ayy
"Ayy
"Ayy
"ap
```

Flag `>` in `cpoptions` inserts a line break before the appended text.

Answer (score 5):

If all those lines share a pattern you can `:help :copy` (or its shortest alternative `:help :t`) them all at once with:

```
:g/pattern/t<line number>
```

Comment: This pastes in inverse order. I have a list that goes 1-40, and the paste goes 40-1. How could one paste in order?

Answer (score 1):

I have this line in my .vimrc

```
nnoremap yY :let @"=@".getline('.')."\n"<CR>
```

Pressing `yY` appends the line under the cursor to the unnamed register.

Use it like this:
First press `yy` to yank line under cursor.

Then press `yY` on several other lines.

Finally press `p` to put all these line somewhere.